# how to animate a set of images?

Tags: iphone

how to animate a set of images, but I have a large set of images, 300 to be exact,

```
 Background.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"001.jpg"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"002.jpg"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"003.jpg"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"004.jpg"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"005.jpg"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"006.jpg"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"007.jpg"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"008.jpg"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"009.jpg"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"010.jpg"],
                                  nil];
```

and I dont wanna go all the way up to 300 by typing, is there a solution for this? 
Could I use a loop for this?

Comment: I think it will be good to play GIF image directly instead of using number of images.. for animation.. This will reduce your Bundle size... and easy to manage resources... below is my answer for the same..

Comment: If this helped you then you can also contribute... thanks.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A loop might look like this

```
NSMutableArray *animationImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:300];

for (int i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d.jpg", i];
    [animationImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
}

Background.animationImages = animationImages;
```

The format specifier `%03d` means an integer padded with 0's to give a minimum field width of 3.

**BUT**

depending on the size of your images you may well run out of memory and have your app terminated.

---

#### Side note

`Background` is not a very good name for a variable on Objective-C. The convention is to start variable names with a lowercase letter and then use camel case after that.

Comment: should I resize them in a specific size?

Answer (score 4):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d.jpg", i];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
    [array addObject:img];
}

Background.animationImages = array;
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Use GIF images to play animation. Playing GIF files with OpenGLES is the good practice and I believe it is the best way to play animation.

Follow the Git Link: https://github.com/jamesu/glgif